# Celery file upload

Tags: file-upload, celery, django-celery, pootle

Is it possible to make celery process file uploads? 
I'm using pootle in my django project and some files to be translated are being uploaded for too long. As far as I understand celery tries to serialize the arguments of the executing function, and since one of them is a file, execution gets stuck. 
I wouldn't like to modify pootle's behaviour(even if possible), so how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Pootle makes use of [RQ](http://python-rq.org/), so that would be a more natural fit for background jobs.

I assume you are using `update_stores` for uploading the files, rather then the UI.  The UI can potentially timeout. While `update_stores` does not background it is easier to safely execute and build into scripts.